# the cardinal of the set of left cosets the same as the cardinal of the set of right cosets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

is $|G/H| = |H/G|$ where $G/H$ is the set of left cosets of H in G, and $H/G$ the set of right cosets of H in G?

I know that $|gH| = |H| = |Hg|$ but I don't see how $|G/H| = |H/G|$, even though wikipedia states it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that the mapping $f : G/H \to H/G$ given by $f(gH) = Hg^{-1}$ is a bijection.

Comment: what motivated the $g^{-1}$?

Comment: Think about what happens when you take the inverse of every element of $gH$. A typical element of $gH$ is $gh$ for some $h$ in $H$, whose inverse is $h^{-1}g^{-1}$, an element of $Hg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that $|G/H| = \frac{|G|}{|H|} = |H\backslash G|$.

Comment: would lagrange's theorem be appropriate to show this?

Comment: In fact, you use this to prove Lagrange's theorem! The group $G$ is the disjoint union of the left (or right) cosets of $H$.

Comment: The proof with the explicit bijection holds also for infinite index; but this is surely good for finite groups.

Comment: Sure, the proof with the explicit bijection is in this sense better.